# How can I simplify this to one sentence?

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to simplify this in VBA, is it possible?

```
On Error Resume Next

 [B11] = "=Y11"
 [B12] = "=Y12" 
 [B13] = "=Y13"
 [B14] = "=Y14"
 [B15] = "=Y15"
 [B16] = "=Y16"
 ...

End Sub
```

Comment: Note: Never use `On Error Resume Next` without proper error handling. This line as you did just hides error messages but the errors still occur, you just cannot see them. This way you cannot debug/find any errors in your code. Remove that line or replace it with an error handling!

Comment: thank you, but that's because i didnt put the rest of the stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Range("B11:B16") = "=Y11"
```

Comment: Or `[B11:B16] = "=Y11"`, following OP's original syntax.

Comment: @AntiDrondert potato / "potato" , I prefer my method.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
for i=11 to 16
    Range("B"& i) = "=Y"& i
next i
```